# Nodejs, How to reconstruct the response of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i reconstract the response of data according to the ***hierarchylevel*** and the ***parentfoldersid***? please consider the parentfolder can be multiple and the subfolder can create another folder. I use the simplest example in order to understand what i mean,

note: please see the desired response below, thanks

my code

```
        ...
        const res1 = results.rows
        let newjson = [];
        for (let x =0; x < res1.length ; x++)
        {
          newjson[x] = {
            id :res1[x]['id'],
            name :res1[x]['name'],
            hierarchylevel :res1[x]['hierarchylevel'],
            parentfoldersid :res1[x]['parentfoldersid']
          }
        }
       res.status(200).json(newjson);
       ....
```

actual result

```
    {
          id: 442,
          name: "Leadership1",
          hierarchylevel: 1,
          parentfoldersid: 0,
    },
   {
          id: 475,
          name: "testv1",
          hierarchylevel: 2,
          parentfoldersid: 442
   },
  {
         id: 476,
         name: "testv2",
         hierarchylevel: 2,
         parentfoldersid: 442,
   },
  {
         id: 539,
         name: "testv2",
         hierarchylevel: 3,
         parentfoldersid: 476
  }
```

What i want result

```
{
      id: 442,
      name: "Leadership1",
      hierarchylevel: 1,
      parentfoldersid: 0, //parentfolder
      children: [
        {
          id: 475,  //subfolder
          name: "testv1",
          hierarchylevel: 2,
          parentfoldersid: 442
        },
        {
          id: 476, //subfolder
          name: "testv2",
          hierarchylevel: 2,
          parentfoldersid: 442,
          children: [
            {
              id: 539, //subfolder created inside the subfolder
              name: "testv2",
              hierarchylevel: 3,
              parentfoldersid: 476
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
```

I used the logic of Muhammad

and this is the result

```
[
{
"trfoldersid": 442,
"name": "Leadership1",
"parentfoldersid": 0,
"hierarchylevel": 1,
"childrens":[
{
"trfoldersid": 475,
"name": "testv1",
"parentfoldersid": 442,
"hierarchylevel": 2,
"childrens":[]
},
{
"trfoldersid": 476,
"name": "testv2",
"parentfoldersid": 442,
"hierarchylevel": 2,
"childrens":[{"trfoldersid": 539, "name": "testv2%20sub%20%20folder%201", "parentfoldersid": 476, "awsobjectkey": "",…]
}
]
},
{
"trfoldersid": 540,
"name": "Leadership2",
"parentfoldersid": 0,
"hierarchylevel": 1,
"childrens":[]
},
{
"trfoldersid": 475,
"name": "testv1",
"parentfoldersid": 442,
"hierarchylevel": 2,
"childrens":[]
},
{
"trfoldersid": 476,
"name": "testv2",
"parentfoldersid": 442,
"hierarchylevel": 2,
"childrens":[
{"trfoldersid": 539, "name": "testv2%20sub%20%20folder%201", "parentfoldersid": 476, "awsobjectkey": "",…}
]
}
]
```

this is the correct result

```
[
{
"id": 442,
"name": "Leadership1",
"parentfoldersid": 0,
"hierarchylevel": 1,
"childrens":[
{
    "id": 475,
    "name": "testv1",
    "parentfoldersid": 442,
    "hierarchylevel": 2,
    "childrens":[]
},
    {
    "id": 476,
    "name": "testv2",
    "parentfoldersid": 442,
    "hierarchylevel": 2,
    "childrens":[{"id": 539, "name": "testv2%20sub%20%20folder%201", "parentfoldersid": 476]
    }
    ]
    },
},
{
"id": 540,
"name": "Leadership2",
"parentfoldersid": 0,
"hierarchylevel": 1,
"childrens":[]
},
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is simple: Iterate trough your response array and return a new array `resNew`.

First, sort the response array by `hierarchylevel`, this enables you to push/update your `resNew` as you go from one folder to another. This will also ensure that folders with lower `hierarchylevel` (i.e. closer to root folder) are inserted into `resNew` before their child folders.

As you iterate trough the `res` array, in the `for` loop, check if the folder is top-level (i.e. if `parentfoldersid == 0` or `hierarchylevel == 1`).

If the current folder is top-level folder, simply push that folder into `resNew`. On the other hand, if the folder is NOT a top-level folder, you have to insert it into the `resNew` using `insertJSON()` function.

`insertJSON()` function updates your `resNew` by inserting the current folder in the `for` loop into the correct parent folder. The function takes 2 parameters - first param is the folder that you want to insert, the 2nd param is the current state of `resNew`.

In the `insertJSON()` function, first convert both the current folder and current `resNew` to JSON string so you can use Regex to find the correct parent folder and insert your current folder into its `"childrens":[` property. After the insertion, the function returns updated `resNew` as an object.

```js
var res = [
  {
    id: 442,
    name: 'Leadership1',
    hierarchylevel: 1,
    parentfoldersid: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 539,
    name: 'testv2',
    hierarchylevel: 3,
    parentfoldersid: 476,
  },
  {
    id: 475,
    name: 'testv1',
    hierarchylevel: 2,
    parentfoldersid: 442,
  },
  {
    id: 476,
    name: 'testv2',
    hierarchylevel: 2,
    parentfoldersid: 442,
  },
];

res = res.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.hierarchylevel - b.hierarchylevel;
});

var resNew = [];

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  var obj = res[i];
  obj.childrens = []; // you never know if it has children or not

  if (obj.parentfoldersid === 0) {
    resNew.push(obj);
  } else {
    resNew = insertJSON(obj, resNew);
  }
}

function insertJSON(what, where) {
  var objJSON = JSON.stringify(what);
  var resJSON = JSON.stringify(where);

  var regexStr =
    `(.*?"id":` +
    what.parentfoldersid +
    `,.*,"hierarchylevel":` +
    (what.hierarchylevel - 1) +
    `,"parentfoldersid":\\d+,"childrens":\\[)`;
  var regex = new RegExp(regexStr, 'gm');
  var resArr = resJSON.split(regex);
  resJSON = (resArr[1] + objJSON + resArr[2]).replace(/}{/g, '},{');
  return JSON.parse(resJSON);
}

console.log(resNew);
```

Comment: Hi, how to rename that `childrens` to `children`?

Comment: @MayYie I updated the answer and replaced `children` with `childrens`

Comment: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: can you please explain your code?

Comment: @MayYie On what line is the type error? Are you using a a JSLinter? I will add comments to my code

Comment: I think here     `res= res.sort(function (a, b) {`

Comment: `getFolder (C:\Users\May Vie\Desktop\github\school-api\controllers\document.Controller.js:186:22)`

Comment: i fixed it, but i receive this error now

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: why you have `obj.children = [];`?

Comment: I am getting error here `var regexStr =
    `(.*?"id":` +
    what.parentfoldersid +
    `,.*,"hierarchylevel":` +
    (what.hierarchylevel - 1) +
    `,"parentfoldersid":\\d+,"childrens":\\[)`;`

Comment: @MayYie I used `obj.children = [];` because you never know if that  current folder will have children or not :D . In the end, you can always replace all `,childrens":'[]` with empty strings `''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237754/discussion-between-may-yie-and-dvn-anakin).

Answer (score 0):

I used your response array to solve the problem. I hope It will work for you.

```js
const response = [
  {
    id: 442,
    name: "Leadership1",
    hierarchylevel: 1,
    parentfoldersid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 475,
    name: "testv1",
    hierarchylevel: 2,
    parentfoldersid: 442
  },
  {
    id: 476,
    name: "testv2",
    hierarchylevel: 2,
    parentfoldersid: 442
  },
  {
    id: 539,
    name: "testv2",
    hierarchylevel: 3,
    parentfoldersid: 476
  }
];

let hirarichy = [];
let processed = [];
response.forEach((item, index) => {
  /* process only if it is not already processed */
  if (processed.includes(item.id)) return;

  /* retrieve the parent direct children */
  const childrens = response.filter(
    (child) => child.parentfoldersid === item.id
  );

  /* now retrieve children of childrens */
  let parentHirarichy = {
    ...item,
    childrens: childrens.map((child) => {
      return {
        ...child,
        childrens: response.filter((t) => t.parentfoldersid === child.id)
      };
    })
  };

  /* store the nodes id's that are processed to avoid duplication */
  const processedNodes = [];
  parentHirarichy.childrens.forEach((child) => {
    processedNodes.push(child.id, ...child.childrens.map((t) => t.id));
  });
  processed = [...processedNodes];

  /* finally push the node */
  hirarichy.push(parentHirarichy);
});
console.log(hirarichy);
```

1. First target direct children
2. Extract the nested children
3. Store the node id's to avoid duplication
4. Finally push the node to main list

**Please accept the answer if it correct !**

Thanks,

Comment: i have a concern please wait the update question ,I used your code or logic

Comment: please see the @Muhammad

Comment: This does not work if you add another folder with `hierarchylevel: 4` - for example `{
    id: 333,
    name: "testv3",
    hierarchylevel: 4,
    parentfoldersid: 539
  }`

Comment: @DVN-Anakin yes youre right, when i added another folder with `hierarchylevel: 4`